# Setting Up Apache Server on Windows 7(Specifically To Use SSI)

Tags: windows, apache, .htaccess

Are there any specific setup tips regarding using Apache on Wondows(7)
I am just trying to test a website locally.
Again specifically, what should be kept in mind regarding running html SSI's?
I have read the Apache website regarding this and I have my pages running properly on a test host online but cannot repeat my success locally.
I have spent a few hours reading various websites for help without success.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Server Side Includes? A few configuration lines is all it takes...

My WampDeveloper setup comes with SSI enabled by default using this:

```
<IfModule include_module>
    <Directory "D:/WampDeveloper/Websites/*/webroot">
        Options +Includes
        AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .html .shtml
    </Directory>
</IfModule>
```

Which turns on SSI for all the website DocumentRoot folders.

httpd.conf ofcourse has this also:

```
LoadModule include_module modules/mod_include.so
```

You should be able to modify the above for your own setup fairly easy.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I uninstalled my Apache, PHP and MySQL and installed WAMP. Everything works perfectly without any tweaking whatsoever. Wow. Thats all I can say. Thank you for your input. Problem seems to be solved.